# Pspice error ERROR(ORPSIM-16362): Name on .ENDS does not match .SUBCKT for LMV751

Tags: pspice, .lib

I downloaded the Texas Instrument's LMV 751([link is here](https://www.ti.com/product/LMV751) ) opamp in .cir format. Then, I made a .lib conversation and associated it with the model. However, I get an error like

ERROR(ORPSIM-16362): Name on .ENDS does not match .SUBCKT

what is the problem?
[image]

Comment: Does the information in [FAQ PSPICE-FOR-TI: PSpice gave an error message about missing ".ENDS" in my model\ or, PSpice says "Name on .ENDS does not match .SUBCKT"\. How to fix this?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/simulation-hardware-system-design-tools-group/sim-hw-system-design/f/simulation-hardware-system-design-tools-forum/969668/faq-pspice-for-ti-pspice-gave-an-error-message-about-missing-ends-in-my-model-or-pspice-says-name-on-ends-does-not-match-subckt-how-to-fix-this) help to resolve the issue? I'm not a user of Psipce to know if will fix the error, and found from a search.

Comment: Thanks Chester thats worked, send as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following information in [[FAQ] PSPICE-FOR-TI: PSpice gave an error message about missing ".ENDS" in my model (or, PSpice says "Name on .ENDS does not match .SUBCKT"). How to fix this?](https://e2e.ti.com/support/tools/simulation-hardware-system-design-tools-group/sim-hw-system-design/f/simulation-hardware-system-design-tools-forum/969668/faq-pspice-for-ti-pspice-gave-an-error-message-about-missing-ends-in-my-model-or-pspice-says-name-on-ends-does-not-match-subckt-how-to-fix-this) help to resolve the issue:

> A simulation error often happens when using 3rd party models. There are two error messages:
>
> **Missing .ENDS in SUBCKT**
>
> or
>
> **Name on .ENDS does not match .SUBCKT**
>
> The root cause is the same. This problem is caused by the end-of-line character.
>
> The Windows system uses 2 characters, "CR" (carriage return) plus "LF"  (line feed) to mark the end of a line. PSpice must delete the last 2 characters from each line to understand the input file.

Where the above FAQ describes some options to correct the line endings to resolve the error.

I'm not a user of Psipce to know if will fix the error, and found by searching for the text of the error message.

The FAQ also contains:

> If the model is produced by TI, please let us know and we'll get it fixed.

Since the question gives a link to a model on the TI website, consider reporting the error to TI.